# how to solve for dy/dx if adding 2 fractions

Tags: derivatives

I've been stuck on trying to figure out how to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for this problem:

$$y= \frac{4}{x^3} + \frac{1}{8}\cdot e^{-8x}$$

Thanks for any and all help in advance.

Comment: The derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives. So, if $y=a+b$, then $y'=a'+b'$.

Comment: Is the edit right ?

Comment: Yeah thanks for the edit, its correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: we have $$y=\frac{4}{x^3}+\frac{1}{8}e^{-8x}=4x^{-3}+\frac{1}{8}e^{-8x}$$
Apply the following formula $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{ax})=ae^{ax}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\frac{dy }{dx} = 4(-3) x^{-3-1} + \frac{1}{8}(-8)e^{-8x}$$ by applying the following formula from @Harish $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{ax})=ae^{ax}$$

Answer (score 0):

this might help, rearrange:

$y=4x^{-3} +  \frac {1} {8}*e^{-8x}$ then take the derivative (use power rule on the first piece and add it to the derivative of the second piece)
$\frac {dy}{dx}=-12x^{-2}-e^{-8x}$.